# Connection is not getting established from react socket-io client to flask-socket-io server for real time update

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Just for learning purpose, I am trying to establish a **connection between react and flask with SOCKET.io**  to get real time updates.

But, sadly I am not able to **establish a connection between client socket.io to sever socket.io till now**.

I followed several blogs and explored GitHub issues, but none of them had helped me.

**Codes**

**1. React codes**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
    import io from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io";
    import "./App.css";
    
    const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
    
    function App() {
      const [data, setData] = useState("");
    
      const setRecords = (response) => {
        console.log("response", response);
        setData(response.records);
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        // const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);   // >>>>> Not Working
        const socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT, { rejectUnauthorized: false }); //{ transports:["websocket"]}
        console.log("connected", socket);
        socket.on("success", (data) => console.log(data));
   
        // socket.on("FetchRecords");
        // socket.emit("FetchRecords");
        // socket.on("SendingRecords", setRecords);
    
        // socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
        //   setResponse(data);
        // });
      }, []);
      return (
        <div className="App">WEBSOCKET with FLASK and REACT...{data.length}</div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Now if I see the logs in the console, it is being disconnected.
[image: Frontend Console]

**2. Backend Code**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from mongoConnect import todo
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('CONNECT EVENT happened...')
    emit('success', {'data': 'Connected'})


@socketio.on('FetchRecords')
def fetch_all_records():
    records = todo.find({})
    print('fetch_all_records', len(records))
    response = jsonify({'code': 200, 'records': records})
    print(response)
    emit('sendingRecords', response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=5000)
```

Logs of backend (using geevent-websocket)

[image: backend_logs_1]

[image: backend_logs_2]

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong? Weirdly none of them had the problem like me...
Here are the blogs and issues I checked...

**1.** [**React Native: unable to establish the socket connection**](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/716)
**2.** [**Simple Chat-App with React & Flask**](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/simple-chat-app-with-react-flask-b2ae72404fcb)
**3.** [**Socket.IO, React and Node.js: Going Real-Time**](http://%20https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem too.

Try uninstall socket.io-client and install version 2.3.1 `npm i socket.io-client@2.3.1`

The old version works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is to make sure there isn't another server running on the same port you're trying to connect to.

Simple mistake but it could happen